# Add text between strings as needed

Tags: python, regex, string, python-3.x

I want something that replaces text between two occurences of the same string as follows:

```
Input:- "abcdefghcd","cd","k"
Output :- "abkefghk"
```

You might think that a simple thing such a .replace() would work, but actually its not that. Some more examples-

```
Input:- "123*45","*","u"
Output:- "123*45" # No change because there aren't two occurences of "*"

Input:- "text*text*hello*text","*","k"
Output:- "textktextkhello*text"
```

I don't know how to do it. Any ideas?

Answer (score 2):

Count the occurrences and only replace the first n-1 of them if n is odd.

```
>>> s, find, replace = "text*text*hello*text", "*", "k"
>>> s.replace(find, replace, 2*(s.count(find)//2))
'textktextkhello*text'
```

Answer (score 0):

what about splitting and joining :

```
Input = "abcdefghcd"
replace_="cd"
with_='k'


data=Input.split(replace_)
print(with_.join(data))
```

output:

```
abkefghk
```

Comment: This is nice idea, but it only works for the first case.

Answer (score 0):

Split the string and only substitute pattern if more than 2 occurrences are found.

```
>>> replace = lambda s, pat, sub: "".join([x + sub for x in s.split(pat) if x]) if len(s.split(pat))>2 else s
>>> replace("abcdefghcd", "cd", "k")
'abkefghk'
>>> replace("123*45", "*", "u")
'123*45'
```

---

If you favor an explicit function (recommended) instead of a one-liner:

```
def replace(s, pat, sub, occ=2):
    """Return a string of replaced letters unless below the occurrences."""
    if len(s.split(pat)) > occ:
        return "".join([x + sub for x in s.split(pat) if x]) 
    return s
```